# WCF service deploy The type or namespace name 'MVC' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have created a WCF REST web service using [WCF REST SERVICE TEMPLATE](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd). I am trying to deploy it using Visual studio 2010 Publish menu. It creates Virual directory in IIS but when I try to browse it, It gives error:

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'MVC' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 63:         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
**Line 64:         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />**
Line 65:         <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
Line 66:         <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
Line 67:         <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
```

on line 64 that MVC is missing. I added reference using NUGET and now it says

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have Visual studio 2012 installed on my system. Is it because IIS is looking for asp.net 4.5 where as application pool is asp.net 4.0 ?

Please suggest

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization -Version 1.0.0` via Package Manager?

Comment: No but why it is required ?

Comment: I am not using mvc even then it is asking for mvc missing

Comment: As you suggested, it may be required if the server you're deploying to doesn't have .NET 4.5 installed. To add to the confusion, 4.5 is an in-place, er, replacement for 4.0, yet you can't set the AppPool to 4.5, just 4.0.